# Programmatically find the name of referenced pictures in Word documents

Tags: macos, ms-office

While writing a thesis I had somehow renamed one of the referenced picture files which made Word tell me it could not show the referenced picture. But I had long since forgot what the picture was showing... So how can I find the name of the referenced picture file?

I am running Office 2011 on Mac, and it is a docx file (OpenXML).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know VBA, but after remembering the docx is just a zipped xml file I came up with the following Python solution for listing all referenced pictures:

```
import sys,xml.dom.minidom; 
from zipfile import ZipFile;

z=ZipFile(sys.argv[1]); 
f=z.open("word/document.xml"); 
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(f); 
for e in doc.getElementsByTagName("pic:cNvPr")];
    print e.attributes["name"].value
```

If saving this as a `word-pictures` you can call it on a document:

```
$ word-pictures ../thesis.docx
aurora_screen_reference.png
Grid2aib.jpg
__media-query-css3.tiff
__dom_html.tiff
aurora_screen_reference.png
interaksjonsskisse_science_full_rwd_breaking.png.tiff
motivasjonsprisme.png
EvacPrepbackgrndUK1-forside.tiff
SatTrackingMapA3__bilde.tiff
Volcgraph-forside.tiff
```

Another quick solution you can use to find a specific picture preceding a string is this:

```
 unzip -p ../thesis.docx word/document.xml \
 | xmllint --format /dev/stdin \
 | grep -B100 'some string immediately after a picture' \
 | grep --color  'pic:cNvPr'
```

Which printed  `<pic:cNvPr id="1" name="aurora_screen_reference.png"/>` in my case.